# How to convert action script 2 to action script 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

Code is
  import mx.events.EventDispatcher;
  import Proxy;

Following is the class definition.

```
class XMLLoad extends EventDispatcher{
public var XML_NODE_TYPE_TEXT = 3;
public var XML_NODE_TYPE_ELEMENT = 1;
private var xmlPath:String;
private var xmlObj:Object;
private var classObj:Object;
private var data_xml:XML;
private var loadedxmldata:XML;
private var success:Boolean;

public static var LOAD_SUCCESS:String = "xmlObjCreated";
public static var LOAD_FAILED:String = "xmlObjFailed";
```

all this code falls in the same class
Following are the functoins in the class above

```
public function XMLLoad() {
    loadedxmldata = new XML();
    classObj = new Object();
}

public function setXMLObject(_xmlPath:String):Void {
    xmlPath = _xmlPath;
    data_xml = new XML();
    data_xml.ignoreWhite = true;
    data_xml.load(xmlPath) 
    data_xml.onLoad = Proxy.create(this, loadXml, success, data_xml);
}

public function getLoadedXML():XML {
    return loadedxmldata;
}

private function loadXml(success):Void {
    if (success) {
        loadedxmldata = data_xml
        xmlObj = XMLDocToObject(data_xml);
        var eveObj:Object = {target:this, type:LOAD_SUCCESS, xmlObj:xmlObj, nativeXMLObj:data_xml}
        dispatchEvent(eveObj)
    } else {
        var eveObj:Object = {target:this, type:LOAD_FAILED, nativeXMLObj:data_xml}
        dispatchEvent(eveObj)
    }
}

public function XMLDocToObject(oXML):Array {
    var obj = [];
    if (oXML == null) {
        return obj;
    }
    var eRoot = oXML.firstChild;
    if (eRoot != null) {
        obj = buildObject(obj, eRoot);
    }
    return obj;
}

private function buildObject(obj, eItem):Array {
    var idx, eChild;
    var oTarget;
    while (eItem != null) {
        idx = eItem.nodeName;
        if (eItem.nodeType == XML_NODE_TYPE_ELEMENT) {
            oTarget = buildObject({}, eItem.firstChild);
            for (var attrib in eItem.attributes) {
                oTarget[attrib] = eItem.attributes[attrib];
            }
            if (eItem.nodeValue != null) {
                oTarget._value = eItem.nodeValue;
            } else {
                eChild = eItem.firstChild;
                if (eChild != null) {
                    if (eChild.nodeType == XML_NODE_TYPE_TEXT) {
                        if (eChild.nodeValue != null) {
                            oTarget._value = eChild.nodeValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        if (obj[idx]._type != 'array') {
            obj[idx] = [obj[idx]];
            obj[idx]._type = "array";
            obj[idx][0] = oTarget;
        } else {
            obj[idx][obj[idx].length] = oTarget;
        }
    }
```

These are the functions. in the class.

Comment: Why not just re-write it in AS-3 ?  AS-2 is going to be gone really soon, and now that Flex is being sold to Spoon...

Comment: can you post the AS2 code in question? Sometimes porting to AS3 can take very little work, but it's hard to say for a specific case without seeing the source.

Comment: I have created near about 4000 animations in AS2. Its a very big task to me to convert it into AS3. Is there any automated method or anything else.

Comment: Wow! 4000 animations ! Could you post an example of one ? Also, if you used a Tweening library, the code should be fairly easy to port.

Answer (score 2):

What I would recommend is take out the AS2 swf. Create an AS3 wrapper load your as2 swf. And you can communicate between the two, if you need to.

Comment: Why not just re-write it in AS-3 ?  AS-2 is going to be gone really soon, and now that Flex is being sold to Spoon...

Comment: Depends on the amount of work you are willing to undertake and the scope of the project.

Comment: I have created near about 4000 animations in AS2. Its a very big task to me to convert it into AS3. Is there any automated method or anything else.

Comment: Uhm, as he did say you could use an actionscript-3 loader to do it, cast them as MovieClips (in .swf form) and let them run as is.. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Transforming AS2 to AS3 is not an easy task to perform. There are several conceptual differences between the 2, and even though a smart human with good knowledge can make the required changes, the actual functioning of the code won't be the same, they'll accomplish the same goal, but not the same way.

If you want that done, you're gonna have to do it yourself, understand what the 4000 animations use and do, and write your own converter that will convert them your way. If you don't know AS3 or AS2, paste the code here and if it's simple enough I could translate 1 of them for you.